# saving an invoice in asp.net core MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

```
I've three Models :
```

Repairs :

```
public class Repairs
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    
    public int TaskNumber { get; set; }
   
    public int PiecePrice { get; set; }
  
    public int WorkerPrice { get; set; }
  
    public string RepairLocation { get; set; }
    
    public int CarsID { get; set; }
    public int RepairTypesID { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy--MM--dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    
    public DateTime TaskDate { get; set; }

    //navegation Property
    
    public Cars Cars { get; set; }
    
    public RepairTypes RepairTypes { get; set; }
}
```

RepairTypes :

```
  public class RepairTypes
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RepairTypeName { get; set; }

    //navegation Property
    public ICollection<Repairs> Repairs { get; set; }
}
```

Cars:

```
   public class Cars
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CarNumber { get; set; }
    public string CarLetter { get; set; }

    //navegation Property
    public ICollection<Repairs> Repairs { get; set; }
    
}
```

And this is the create methods in Repairs Controller :

```
 public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["CarNumber"] = new SelectList(_context.Cars, "ID", "CarNumber");
        ViewData["RepairTypeName"] = new SelectList(_context.RepairTypes, "ID", "RepairTypeName");
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Repairs/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to.
    // For more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("TaskNumber,PiecePrice,WorkerPrice,RepairLocation,CarsID,RepairTypesID,TaskDate")] Repairs repairs)
    {
       
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(repairs);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));              
            }              
    
        ViewData["CarNumber"] = new SelectList(_context.Cars, "ID", "CarNumber");
        ViewData["RepairTypeName"] = new SelectList(_context.RepairTypes, "ID", "RepairTypeName");
        return View(repairs );

    }
```

and the View :

```
        <form asp-action="Create">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TaskNumber" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="TaskNumber" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TaskNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="PiecePrice" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="PiecePrice" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="PiecePrice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="WorkerPrice" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="WorkerPrice" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="WorkerPrice" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RepairLocation" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="RepairLocation" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="RepairLocation" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="CarsID" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="CarsID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.CarNumber"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="RepairTypesID" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="RepairTypesID" class ="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.RepairTypeName"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="TaskDate" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="TaskDate" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="TaskDate" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

I want to save more than RepairTypeName in the database then save it with the same date and rest of properties

ex: I want to save list of items in HTML page then send it to the controller and do a foreach loop to save each item but with the same date

Comment: Hi @Levi , In your model design , `Repairs` and `RepairTypes` is many-to-one relationship , one table `Repairs` can only correspond to one table `RepairTypes` , So It is impossible to `save more than RepairTypeName in the database then save it with the same date and rest of properties`.

Comment: can't it be saved like this :

  TaskNumber = 12345
  RepairTypeName = (any Name)
and another row in the same table
TaskNumber = 12345
RepairTypeName =(anotherName)

if not what should I do

Comment: I have post a one-to-many relationship in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

in you model design , `Repairs` only contains one `RepairTypes` , so one `Repairs` can only have one `RepairTypeName` , if you want one `Repairs` correspond to many different `RepairTypeName` in `RepairTypes` , you need change their relationship to one-to-many.

**code:**

```
 public class Repairs
 {
    //.........
    
    public List<RepairTypes> RepairTypes { get; set; }
 }

public class RepairTypes
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string RepairTypeName { get; set; }

    public int RepairsID { get; set; }
    public Repairs repairs { get; set; }
}
```